# Center the Content on the Page using CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a lead generation page. I want to center all the contents on the page to the center when displayed on any browser size.

i tried using vertical align center. But it seems not to work.

Which are the best practices to do so ?

http://play.mink7.com/h/mspre/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just mean centering between left and right edges, you create an element with a fixed width, and declare `margin: auto;` on it.

If you want to center the element both horizontally and vertically, you position it halfway across the page both horizontally and vertically, then pull it back by half of the element's width and height.

For example:

```
.someElement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
}
```

Comment: i tried that. but it doesnt seem to center itself. http://play.mink7.com/h/mspre/

Comment: I don't understand. It looks quite centered to me.

Comment: ah. sorry i was changing and playing with the code :) now it works :)

Answer (score 3):

For me the best way to do it is to make a container div of set width. I normally choose about 900px as pretty much all displays are wider than this now a days. I then centre div by using margin auto.

```
#container { width: 900px; 
margin: 0px auto 0px auto; 
}
```

This will centre the div. Bob's your uncle. 
If you want I can post examples of this.

Mike

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html